# Cant draw same image on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have three canvases adjacent to each other and an image which I want to draw on two of them. The code below draws the image twice on one canvas (as desired), but won't draw it on another canvas, as shown in the screenshot below.

Through debugging, I have established that the line `c1.drawImage(img, x, y, 50, 50);` runs (this can be seen in the console where "here" is output). This should draw the image onto the second canvas, however it doesn't.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xnpys9m/1/

[image]

```js
var area0 = document.getElementById("area-0");
var area1 = document.getElementById("area-1");
var area2 = document.getElementById("area-2");
var c0 = area0.getContext("2d");
var c1 = area1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = area2.getContext("2d");

// Set height and width of areas
area0.width = area1.width = area2.width = 150;
area0.height = area1.height = area2.height = 150;

var arr; // holds all positions
var img;

populate();

function populate() {
  arr = [
    [0, 0],
    [40, 40],
    [170, 0]
  ];

  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {

    // for each position in array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var x = arr[i][0]; // x position
      var y = arr[i][1]; // y position
      draw(x, y);
    }
  }
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png";
}

// Draw onto canvas
function draw(x, y) {
  var area;
  // Work out which area to draw in
  if (x < area0.width + 1) {
    area = 0;
  } else if (x < (area0.width * 2) + 1) {
    area = 1;
  } else if (x < (area0.width * 3) + 1) {
    area = 2;
  }

  // Draw onto correct area
  if (area == 0) {
    c0.drawImage(img, x, y, 50, 50);
  } else if (area == 1) {
    console.log("here");
    c1.drawImage(img, x, y, 50, 50);
  } else if (area == 2) {
    c2.drawImage(img, x, y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

```css
#canvases {
  width: 470px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <canvas id="area-0"></canvas>
  <canvas id="area-1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="area-2"></canvas>
</div>
```

I thought the problem could be related to drawing the same image across multiple canvases, however removing the first two items from the array `arr` doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to draw you images and have your functions calculate their position in this manner then you must account for the canvas position relative to the window. You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the coordinates and then subtract the `x` value from the x in `drawImage()`. Same for the y coordinate. This accounts for the body margin too.

```js
var area0 = document.getElementById("area-0");
var area1 = document.getElementById("area-1");
var area2 = document.getElementById("area-2");
var c0 = area0.getContext("2d");
var c1 = area1.getContext("2d");
var c2 = area2.getContext("2d");
// Set height and width of areas
area0.width = area1.width = area2.width = 150;
area0.height = area1.height = area2.height = 150;
let a0Bnds = area0.getBoundingClientRect();
let a1Bnds = area1.getBoundingClientRect();
let a2Bnds = area2.getBoundingClientRect();

var arr; // holds all positions
var img;

populate();

function populate() {
  arr = [
    [0, 0],
    [40, 40],
    [170, 0]
  ];

  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {

    // for each position in array
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var x = arr[i][0]; // x position
      var y = arr[i][1]; // y position
      draw(x, y);
    }
  }
  img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png";
}

// Draw onto canvas
function draw(x, y) {
  var area;
  // Work out which area to draw in
  if (x < area0.width + 1) {
    area = 0;
  } else if (x < (area0.width * 2) + 1) {
    area = 1;
  } else if (x < (area0.width * 3) + 1) {
    area = 2;
  }
//console.log(a1Bnds.x)
  // Draw onto correct area
  if (area == 0) {
    c0.drawImage(img, x - a0Bnds.x, y - a0Bnds.y, 50, 50);
  } else if (area == 1) {
    c1.drawImage(img, x - a1Bnds.x, y - a1Bnds.y, 50, 50);
  } else if (area == 2) {
    c2.drawImage(img, x - a2Bnds.x, y - a2Bnds.y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

```css
#canvases {
  width: 470px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvases">
  <canvas id="area-0"></canvas>
  <canvas id="area-1"></canvas>
  <canvas id="area-2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You draw the third image at x coordinate 170, however, the canvas is only 150 wide.

Comment: I think that could be it! Such a simple mistake, I was using the x coordinate relative to the page without realising it should be relative to the canvas. I'll try this an get back to you.